# Laravel 5.2 Conditional Update to Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, conditional-statements

How do I update a database column based on a value from a different column?

I have a query like the following which pulls current usage (example: 200):

```
$currentusage = CurrentPercentageModel::select('current_usage')->where('name', '=', 'User Name')->get();
```

I would like to update the same value +1 after the each time it passes certain conditions.

My `save` query would look like this and adds a new row to the table with the new value (example: 201):

```
$currentusage = $currentusage + 1;
$savecurrentusage = new CurrentPercentageModel;
$savecurrentusage->current_usage = $currentusage;
$savecurrentusage->save();
```

How do I update the same value from the one I pull from my query?

Comment: Tried increment https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit messy but should works

```
$model = CurrentPercentageModel::where('name', '=', 'User Name')->first();
$model->current_usage += 1;
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add 1 to one of the fields, I guess the simplest way will be using [Query Builder's `increment()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#updates) method:

```
DB::table('current_percentage')->increment('current_usage');
```

If you want to use Eloquent, you can do this:

```
$current = CurrentPercentageModel::where('name', '=', 'User Name')->first();
$current->update(['current_usage' => ++$current->current_usage]);
```

Comment: You can call `increment()` on an Eloquent model directly too.

Comment: @Josh, I've just checked, Eloquent has `increment()` method too. Didn't know that, thanks. )

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$currentPercent = CurrentPercentageModel::where('name', '=', 'User Name')->first();
 $currentusage = $currentPercent->currentusage + 1;
 $currentPercent->current_usage = $currentusage;
 $currentPercent->save();
```